# Angular9 / Change [src] folder hierarchy

Tags: angular, directory, angular9

in an Angular9 app I have a problem with some imgs that dont load properly. In fact is a folder hierarchy issue. Due to my components structure when I call the heroe.img property of my obj heroe, the img url is bad. This is the one Angular generate calling my obj heroe

```
<img class="img-fluid" src="assets/img/aquaman.png" alt="Aquaman">
```

And this is the one it should be generate:

```
<img class="img-fluid" src="../assets/img/aquaman.png" alt="Aquaman">
```

As you can see the key point is the (../) folder jump. Is there any way to force this specific property call from .html to add this folder jump?
Here my current property call from .html:

alt property works because it doesnt depend on folder structure like imgs did.

Comment: Just use `/assets/img/aquaman.png`

Comment: I tried, but with that slash no image works because all of them are base on the same object with img path as a property

Comment: Maybe you should change the way you save the path so that it is relative to `/` and not the file position